# Running a local hadoop map-reduce does not partition data as expected

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a map-reduce program that calculates the number of occurring bigrams from google ngrams on each decade.
My partitioner is:

```
public static class PartitionerClass extends Partitioner<Bigram, IntWritable> {
    public int getPartition(Bigram key, IntWritable value, int numPartitions) {
        String combined=key.getFirst().toString()+key.getSecond().toString()+key.getDecade().toString();
        return combined.hashCode()%numPartitions;
    }
}
```

I have added a breakpoint but the program does not go through that piece of code.
My main:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
Job job = new Job(conf, "first join");
job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);
job.setPartitionerClass(PartitionerClass.class);
FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));    ///SHOULD BE DECIDED
job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Bigram.class);
job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
```

The code runs not as expected, some data is processed correctly and some isn't.
I really don't know how to debug this.
Any ideas?

Comment: What you mean by some data is not correctly processed?

Comment: and what is the value of numPartitions you are getting...? you should set that in the main method as setNumReduceTasks

Comment: Some data is not processed correctly- In some cases (I can't tell which) the data is being sent to wrong reducer. I think the problem is that I didn't set numPartitions. How can I know the value to set. Isn't it what the partitioner does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The partitioner, given the number of partitions that you give, defines which key goes to which partition. Its job is not to set the number of partitions, but their contents. Each reduce tasks then handles one partition, so at the end, number of partitions = number of reduce tasks = number of output files (is using default settings and not MultipleOutputs).

In order to set the number of partitions, you should use:

`job.setNumReduceTasks(n);`, where `n` is the number that you want.

For instructions (rules of thumb, nothing strict there) on how to set this number, you can read [this post](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HowManyMapsAndReduces).